# How to calculate my inputs to the total id in realtime with pure javascript only?

Tags: javascript

My problem with this is it doesnt respond, i made sure to load with a document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
which helped me reset my inputs with that however, when getting the actual calculation there seems to be no updating, what approach should i look into,

Heres my code,

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

```
document.getElementById("input").onkeyup = function() {calc()};
function calc(){

    var in_bottles = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_bottles').value,);
    var in_bags = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_bags').value, "");
    var in_wrapping = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_wrapping').value, "");
    var in_yogurt = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_yogurt').value, "");
    var in_takeout = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_takeout').value, "");
    var in_cups = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_cups').value, "");
    var in_packaging = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_packaging').value, "");
    var in_detergent = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_detergent').value, "");
    var in_shampoo = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_shampoo').value, "");
    var in_toothbrushes = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_toothbrushes').value, "");
    var in_toothpaste = parseInt(document.getElementById('in_toothpaste').value, "");

    document.getElementById('total_per_year').innerHTML = in_bottles + in_bags + in_wrapping + in_yogurt + in_yogurt + in_takeout + in_cups + in_packaging + in_detergent + in_shampoo + in_toothbrushes + in_toothpaste;
```

From html it looks like this, its apart of a coursework, so the restrictions are i cant edit html, so i think i may need to approach it like this? heres my attempt anyway

### Food & Kitchen

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="in_bottles">Plastic bottles</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_bottles" name="bottles" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.730"> / week</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_bags">Plastic bags</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_bags" name="bags" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.417"> / week</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_wrapping">Food wrapping</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_wrapping" name="wrapping" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.583"> / week</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_yogurt">Yogurt, cream, etc. containers</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_yogurt" name="yogurt" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.383"> / week</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</section>

<section id="sec_packaging">
  <h2>Disposable Containers &amp; Packaging</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="in_takeout">Take-away plastic boxes</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_takeout" name="takeout" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.383"> / month</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_cups">Take-away cups</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_cups" name="cups" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.240"> / month</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_packaging">Plastic-wrapped packages</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_packaging" name="packaging" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.834"> / month</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>

<section id="sec_washing">
  <h2>Bathroom &amp; Laundry</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="in_detergent">Detergent &amp; cleaning product bottles</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_detergent" name="detergent" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.120"> / year</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_shampoo">Shampoo, conditioner &amp; toiletries</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_shampoo" name="shampoo" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.080"> / year</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_toothbrushes">Plastic toothbrushes</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_toothbrushes" name="toothbrushes" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.020"> / year</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td><label for="in_toothpaste">Toothpaste</label></td>
      <td><input id="in_toothpaste" name="toothpaste" type="number" value="0" min="0" data-weight="0.015"> / year</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

### Your Plastic Footprint

```
  <p>Your estimated plastic footprint is <span id="total_per_year">0</span> kg / year.</p>
  <p>The gobal average is ~50 kg / year.</p>
  <p>The USA average is ~84 kg / year.</p>
  <p>The Eurpean average is ~30 kg / year.</p>

  <p><button id="reset">Reset calculator</button></p>
</section>
```

Comment: You haven't declared an ```input``` id but you are trying to call it

Comment: This doesn't look right `document.getElementById("input")` is that a typo or what you are using?

Comment: Hmmm, u got a point, i assumed, based on input i got run it through as an ID, as it comes underneath the "in_bottles" for example, do i have to split it up by attribute so input itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: im back at my computer, here is a whole new answer that cover the old one aswell:

EDIT 2: i added the use of dataset to get the data-weight attribute you use in your example

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('reset');
const total = document.getElementById('total_per_year');
const htmlCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
let inputs = [...htmlCollection];

let totalValue = 0;

function reset() {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.value = 0
  })
  total.innerText = 0;
}

//Add eventlistneres for "change" and "keyup" to all inputs and execute sumTotal when event is triggered
//Note that change is triggered when the user "leaves" the input box or clicks the increment arrows so keyup is added to register direct inputs and update before the user leaves the box

function addEventListeners() {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
      totalValue = 0;
      sumTotal();
    });
      input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
      totalValue = 0;
      sumTotal();
    });
  })
}

//Summerize the value of each imput and set the totalValue and eliminate crazy decimals then display it 
function sumTotal(value) {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    totalValue += Number(input.value) * Number(input.dataset.weight);
  })
  total.innerText = totalValue.toFixed(2);
}

//When the DOM content is loaded we run the function that adds the eventListeners
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  addEventListeners();
})


btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  reset()
})
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" data-weight="0.43" />
<input type="number" value="0" data-weight="0.71" />
<input type="number" value="0" data-weight="1.65" />
<input type="number" value="0" data-weight="1.19" />
<input type="number" value="0" data-weight="2.44" />
<p>Your estimated plastic footprint is <span id="total_per_year">0</span> kg / year.</p>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I had to leave my computer for a while, ill add similar code to update the the total on input change when im back at my computer